# Creating a chessboard like cell field in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically I'm trying to create a sort of chessboard, several smaller squares into a bigger square. I managed to do this in vanilla JS but cant seem to find a solution on how I could transition this to AngularJS. In vanilla JS I basically used a cell ( small square in form of a div ) as a template, made a for loop where I appended the cells to the parent bigger square.

Any ideas ?

Appreciate the help.

Comment: What have you tried (with Angular), and what part are you struggling with? The most basic features introduced in any Angular tutorial should be enough to do this easily.

Comment: I'm struggling designing the chessboard. The first thought was making the chessboard a directive and using ng-repeat to fill it with cells, but the problem is I dont intend on using an array and more then that I would need to repeat a template ( the smaller square )

Comment: What is the intended usage of the board? If you're going to be putting it in several different locations and need its appearance and behavior the same in all of them, a directive would be a reasonable direction, but if not, there are simpler approaches.

Comment: I want to create a battleship game. So at first there would be 2 boards, one for the player ( where he can click the cells and trigger an event, like changing the color of the clicked cell for example ), the other for the npc ( here I'm gonna randomize for auto-picking cells )